# React native debug on windows

Tags: debugging, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native android app that i am currently debugging on a **windows** machine with a **android emulator**.

I can hit http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui

And it tells me that

```
React Native JS code runs inside this Chrome tab.

Press ⌘⌥J to open Developer Tools. Enable Pause On Caught Exceptions for a better debugging experience.

Status: Waiting, press ⌘R in simulator to reload and connect.
```

When I open up the chrome developer tool, I do not see my react code being loaded into the "source" of that tab.

So my question is, how do I make it so that my phone loads the react stuff into the chrome tab? I wish to at least see the console.log stuff appearing in my chrome developer tool.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

OK. Found what to do:

1. Ctrl + M to open up some "developer menu"
2. click on enable remote JS debugging
3. Depending on your react native version, chrome may or may not open up the debugging tab. But in any case, go to localhost:8081/debugger-ui should do it.

Comment: Wow I struggled with this lots, thanks for your Ctrl + M thing! I am using Genymotion and Ctrl + M works in Genymotion too!

Comment: =D Glad i can help.

Comment: Thanks brother, I was also able to use Firefox per your step 3, I just navigated to `localhost:8081/debugger-ui ` in Firefox.

Comment: finally a proper answer